# VBA code takes long time to execute in excel

Tags: vba, excel

The following VBA code takes long time to execute

```
Sub LOOK()

Worksheets("Input").Unprotect ("ds12345")
Dim found As Range
Set found = Sheets("Records").Columns("D").Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 13).Value, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found on row " & found.Row
End If

    Dim iRow As Integer

    iRow = InputBox("Which row?")

    Worksheets("Input").Cells(2, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(4, 2).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 3).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(3, 13).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 4).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(4, 13).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 5).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(10, 3).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 6).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(3, 16).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 7).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(9, 7).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 9).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(12, 7).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 10).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(13, 7).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 11).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(9, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 12).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(94, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 13).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(95, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 14).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(97, 2).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 15).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(20, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 16).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(21, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 17).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(22, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 18).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(23, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 19).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(24, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 20).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(25, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 21).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(26, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 22).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(27, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 23).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(28, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 24).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(29, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 25).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(30, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 26).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(31, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 27).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(32, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 28).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(33, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 29).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(34, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 30).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(20, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 31).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(21, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 32).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(22, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 33).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(23, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 34).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(24, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 35).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(42, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 37).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(43, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 38).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(44, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 39).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(45, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 40).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(46, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 41).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(47, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 42).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(48, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 43).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 44).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 45).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 46).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 8).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 47).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 8).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 48).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 8).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 49).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 50).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 51).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 52).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 53).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 54).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 55).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(65, 18).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 56).Value
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(104, 18).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 76).Value

    If [l8] = [n9] Then
        [K8] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l9] = [n9] Then
        [K9] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l10] = [n9] Then
        [K10] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l12] = [n9] Then
        [K12] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l13] = [n9] Then
        [K13] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l14] = [n9] Then
        [K14] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l15] = [n9] Then
        [K15] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l16] = [n9] Then
        [K16] = "YES"
        End If
    If [l17] = [n9] Then
        [K17] = "YES"
    End If

Worksheets("Input").Protect ("ds12345")
End Sub
```

If this code can be modified to run fast. or, if any alternative VBA code need be written to make it fast to run from worksheet "Input" to extract data from worksheet "Records". Thanks

Comment: If it works it belongs on code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  If it does not work please explain where it goes wrong.

Comment: @ScottCraner: May I beg to differ - there is an endemic problem with the code as written, that penalizes performance by ***multiple orders of magnitude***; and I believe that Financial Analysts who encounter this problem will look to Stack Overflow rather than Code Review for help.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It does not matter where they will look.  StackOverflow is for problematic code, while code review is for help in speeding up code that works.  It is a matter of sniper vs shotgun.  Stack Overflow is a sniper, specific problems.  the betterment of code is too broad for this forum, by the standards set.  Where as it is not for Code Review.  That is why Code review insists that the code works.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens feel free to register and answer questions in a non threatening manor then.  Try to change the atmosphere there instead of changing the rules here.

Comment: work with arrays rather than ranges. you could also wrap your code between ScreenUpdating property

Comment: It seems you've asked pretty much the same question 3 times in the last day... **VBA code takes long time to execute** and don't respond to comments unless you're saying "Thank you, it worked just fine" or "If this VBA code can modified, to run from Input worksheet".  Please - respond to comments, makes us feel like information is at least being taken on board then.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I do to speed up VBA like this is to use Screen Updating

```
Sub LOOK()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Input").Unprotect ("ds12345")
Dim found As Range
Set found = Sheets("Records").Columns("D").Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 13).Value, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found on row " & found.Row
End If

Dim iRow As Integer

iRow = InputBox("Which row?")

Worksheets("Input").Cells(2, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(4, 2).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 3).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(3, 13).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 4).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(4, 13).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 5).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(10, 3).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 6).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(3, 16).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 7).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(9, 7).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 9).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(12, 7).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 10).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(13, 7).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 11).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(9, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 12).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(94, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 13).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(95, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 14).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(97, 2).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 15).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(20, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 16).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(21, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 17).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(22, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 18).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(23, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 19).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(24, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 20).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(25, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 21).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(26, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 22).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(27, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 23).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(28, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 24).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(29, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 25).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(30, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 26).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(31, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 27).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(32, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 28).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(33, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 29).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(34, 1).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 30).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(20, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 31).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(21, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 32).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(22, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 33).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(23, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 34).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(24, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 35).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(42, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 37).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(43, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 38).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(44, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 39).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(45, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 40).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(46, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 41).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(47, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 42).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(48, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 43).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 44).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 45).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 5).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 46).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 8).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 47).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 8).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 48).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 8).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 49).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 50).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 51).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 52).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(58, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 53).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(59, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 54).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(60, 14).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 55).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(65, 18).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 56).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(104, 18).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 76).Value

If [l8] = [n9] Then
    [K8] = "YES"
    End If
If [l9] = [n9] Then
    [K9] = "YES"
    End If
If [l10] = [n9] Then
    [K10] = "YES"
    End If
If [l12] = [n9] Then
    [K12] = "YES"
    End If
If [l13] = [n9] Then
    [K13] = "YES"
    End If
If [l14] = [n9] Then
    [K14] = "YES"
    End If
If [l15] = [n9] Then
    [K15] = "YES"
    End If
If [l16] = [n9] Then
    [K16] = "YES"
    End If
If [l17] = [n9] Then
    [K17] = "YES"
End If

Worksheets("Input").Protect ("ds12345")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

For the cleanliness of the code I would make secondary loops when you have lots of values that incrementally increase such as:

```
Worksheets("Input").Cells(42, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 37).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(43, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 38).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(44, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 39).Value 
Worksheets("Input").Cells(45, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 40).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(46, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 41).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(47, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 42).Value
Worksheets("Input").Cells(48, 11).Value = Worksheets("Records").Cells(iRow, 43).Value
```

We don't have the data so it is hard to say if there was a more efficient way of selecting, but I imagine that using a copy and paste special value would be much quicker for most of this.

Answer (score -2):

Every read from, and write to, an Excel cell carries an immense baggage. Performance for iterative copying to or from a range can run 30 to 100 times faster by doing an array copy of the Range to an array, and then an assignment of the array back to the range.

Just an image, but here is an example of an instance where, even **after** disabling Screen Updating, performance was improved by > 30 times using an array-copy instaed of cell-by-cell copy:

[image]